# Can't get jQuery animations to work with ASP.NET master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to use jQuery to animate a div when a button is clicked. When I click the button nothing happens. In a ASP.NET master page currently have..

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnOne").click(function () {
                $("#blockDiv").animate({ left: '250px' });
                $("#blockDiv").animate({ down: '250px' });
                $("#blockDiv").animate({ right: '250px' });
                $("#blockDiv").animate({ up: '250px' });
            });
        });
    </script> 
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

In a different page I have the declaration of the button and the div that I want to animate...

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOne" Text ="Click Me!" runat="server" /><br/><br/>
<div id="blockDiv" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:gold;"/><br>
```

I am not sure why this is not working, maybe I shouldn't do the JavaScript in the head of the master page?  It is my first time working with master pages and jQuery so I may be 100% off track.

Answer (score 0):

There is a change the CSS properties

**Wrong**

```
 $("#blockDiv").animate({ left: '250px' });
 $("#blockDiv").animate({ down: '250px' });
 $("#blockDiv").animate({ right: '250px' });
 $("#blockDiv").animate({ up: '250px' });
```

**Correct**

```
 $("#blockDiv").animate({ left: '250px' });
 $("#blockDiv").animate({ bottom: '250px' });
 $("#blockDiv").animate({ right: '250px' });
 $("#blockDiv").animate({ top: '250px' });
```

Comment: I made this change and the div will still not move. Thanks for the heads up, it will prevent a headache in the near future.